# Button_to with class and button instead of input type submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

I am trying to create a button that when clicked implements GET request. Instead of input element inside to have button and apply class="btn" to that button. I tried but get an error.

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for  #String:0x00007f9f14017fb0>

Here is what tried:

```
  <%= button_to 'Allow', change_email_notifications_admin_user_path(@user), method: :get, params: { msg: 'allow_all' } do %>
    <button class="btn">'Allow</button>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the block style syntax then you must skip the first argument and put it in the block.

```
<%= button_to change_email_notifications_admin_user_path(@user), method: :get, params: { msg: 'allow_all' } do %>
  Allow
<% end %>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to